# Interaction Test Dashboard missing in Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

According the the [March Release Notes](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/resources/release_notes/march_2015_release/) there is a new 'Interaction Test Dashboard' as per the screenshot below:

[image: Interaction Test Dashboard]

However I can't find this interface anywhere. It's not mentioned in the [Interaction Test Documentation](https://help.exacttarget.com/Views/Pages/HelpTopicPage.aspx?id=11507&epslanguage=en_US#TestAnInteraction). I have tried placing an Interaction in Test Mode, and while this works, I can't figure out how to access this new dashboard. Please can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to put your interaction in test mode.  Then, under the trigger icon within the interaction dashboard, you should see a link called "View Trigger Results."  That link will open up the test dashboard.  Now, unfortunately, the dashboard image in the March release notes is not reflective of what was actually released thus far.

Comment: Thanks Drew, the release notes threw me off. I incorrectly assumed that if a screenshot was included in the public release notes then this feature would be available. Apparently this is not the case

Comment: FYI, the Interaction does not need to be in Test Mode. You can view Trigger Results for all running Interactions.